# Установка django-simple-captcha

Tags: python, django, pycharm, captcha

Установил через командную строку django-simple-captcha. Добавил 'captcha' в список INSTALLED_APPS. Но при миграции возникает ошибка:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha'

В чем может быть проблема и как ее устранить?

Comment: Может, используете виртуальное окружение? Или установили модуль не в ту версию (например, `pip` вместо `pip3`)?

Comment: Да, использую виртуальное окружение. Не знаете, как можно исправить?

Comment: Я имел в виду, активировали ли Вы виртуальное окружение, прежде чем устанавливать модуль? Если нет, то активируйте и установите в него.